# Overheating problem in Samsung NP550P7C Laptop

Tags: 12.04, laptop, samsung, overheating

I've been struggling with some issues. First I will start off with a listing of my hardware.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0de9 (rev ff)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

I have an issue with over heating, the laptop is a week old, and no fans are clogged.

I've tried various solutions, `pwmconfig errors with: /usr/sbin/pwmconfig:` There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed, Jupiter seems to have no effects, and the samsung tools for laptops cannot start the fans.

Typically the system will run at 45 to 56 c on each cpu. The fans simply never kick in. It will slowly hit 67 and then a seconds later lockup.

I have disabled acpi. This resulted in the Fans continuously running and the system locking up after 10 to 15 minutes. Temp was 55 to 57 c. By locked up I mean no GUI control, and not able to switch to console `(ctrl+alt+f1 - f6)`.

I've been through many forum posts, and lots of google results but it seems no real solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have windows and do the fans work there ? Sounds like a hardware fault.

Comment: @mark kirby - I don't think it's a hardware falut. My laptop would reach temperatures exceeding 100 deg. C in Ubuntu while Windows would be just fine (55 deg. C tops). Now it's better than before but it still crosses 70 deg. C.

Comment: Yes the fans work fine in windows, and as stated with acpi=off the fans run non stop. If you search around you begin to find alot of people with new hardware having these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues like this with my laptop (Asus U46.) I switched to version 3.4 of the Linux Kernel and the laptop is heating much less (10 celsius degrees down compared to kernel 3.2)

Just an idea...

Comment: Thanks, I will try switching kernels. Did you have the issue with fans not working and did this add support for your fans?

Comment: The fans were working fine though, it was just getting hotter than usual (when checking temperature with lm-sensors)

Comment: Still no fan control with kernel upgrade.

Comment: @Mr Brown switching kernels may present other issuse, be sure appropriately research this before taking action (if it not too late)

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop seems to have two Graphics Cards, which use Optimus Technology. Have you tried using Bumblebee to disable the Nvidia Graphics Card, when not in use. It won't help with the fan control, but should reduce the heat.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ